# Julia: concat strings with separator (equivalent of R's paste)

Tags: string, concatenation, julia, paste

I have an array of strings that I would like to concatenate together with a specific separator.

```
x = ["A", "B", "C"]
```

Expected results (with sep = `;`):

```
"A; B; C"
```

The R's equivalent would be `paste(x, sep=";")`

I've tried things like `string(x)` but the result is not what I look for...

Comment: Since I hit this from Google while looking for simpler concatenation, worth leaving this as a comment: The general Julia operator for concatenating strings is `*`, rather than `+` like many other languages.  I.e., `"A" * "; " * "B"` yields `"A; B"`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `join`. It is not clear if you want ";" or "; " as a separator.

```
julia> x = ["A", "B", "C"]
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "A"
 "B"
 "C"

julia> join(x, ';')
"A;B;C"

julia> join(x, "; ")
"A; B; C"
```

If you just want `;` then just use a character `';'`as a separator, if you also want the space, you need to use a string: `"; "`